# Unable to install Ubuntu using WUBI

Tags: installation, wubi

I am new to open-source software but I'm very much interested in trying it out and hopefully I can start using Ubuntu soon.

I downloaded `wubi.exe` first and then I used it to install Ubuntu 12.04-LTS desktop.
It said I had to wait for 6 hrs to finish installation. I did wait patiently...but after an hour or so, an error message popped up and said the installation had to be stopped.

This is the exact message I got:

```
IOError:<urlopen error (7,'getaddrinfo failed')
```

It also asked me to check my computer's log files for more information but I do not know how to access the log files.

I'll be grateful for any help with regard to this installation.

Comment: Are you running Wubi as administrator?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I dont see the option to run as an administrator on windows xp.

Comment: I mean being logged in under an account that has administrator access.

Comment: yes i do have administrative access...but how does that affect the installation?

Comment: Wubi requires administrative access to install its bootloader files, which must be added as entries to `boot.ini`, which is protected so only admins can write to it., A similar restriction goes for many programs.

Answer (score 1):

first download the .iso file, and then put the wubi.exe there, and then run wubi.exe, it will be faster, withing 1 hour approx. (disconnect from the internet after downloading file).

The IO error may be because of internet connectivity while installing online.

Comment: can you give me the exact link for the .iso file? thanks.

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com//precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
(for 32 bit)